# Android: Use button to add item to ListView in Fragment

Tags: android

I know lots of people have asked this question, or ones very similar to it, but of all the responses I've read and tried my app still doesn't work. It doesn't crash, but the circular load sign goes on indefinitely.

What I have now is a fragment that contains a button and a `ListView`. I want to be able to add a new item when I click on the button.

Here is my MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if(findViewById(R.id.container) != null) {
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new ListFragment())
                .commit();
          }
        }
     }     
   }
```

My Fragment:

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

private ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayAdapter<String> myListAdapter;
private ListView listView;

public ListFragment() {

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // The ArrayAdapter will take data from a source and
    // use it to populate the ListView it's attached to.
    myListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActivity(),
            R.layout.fragment_element_list,
            R.id.list_item_textview,
            listItems);

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);

    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(
            R.id.listview_list);
    listView.setAdapter(myListAdapter);

    Button b = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.button);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);

    return rootView;

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button:
            listView.setAdapter(myListAdapter); //Adds to the List View
            listItems.add("New Item");
            break;
    }

}
}
```

ActivityMain.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
```

FragmentList.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".ListFragment">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

</FrameLayout>
```

Fragment_element_list.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:id="@+id/list_item_textview">
</TextView>
```

I apologize for my repetitive question. I'm still learning Android and would really appreciate any help on this.

EDIT: Here are the changes I made so far. The only thing that appears is the page loader though.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // The ArrayAdapter will take data from a source and
    // use it to populate the ListView it's attached to.
    myListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActivity(),
            R.layout.fragment_element_list,
            R.id.list_item_textview,
            listItems);

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);

    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(
            R.id.listview_list);
    listView.setAdapter(myListAdapter);

    Button b = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);

    return rootView;

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button:
            listItems.add("New Item");
            myListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            break;
    }

}
```

Also I found in the logcat:
`03-25 10:22:25.343 5617-5617/com.example.kristindiep.appmanager E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null`

Comment: If you call myListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after you add your item to the listItems list, the items should be added to the ListView. And, another thing, you don't to call listView.setAdapter(myListAdapter) more than once. Try it out and let me know

Comment: I took out listView.setAdapter(myListAdapter) from within onCreateView and added in myListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after listtems.add("New Item") but the page still won't load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! It was because ListFragment is a built in class in Android and so it didn't like that I was 'redefining' it.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the items from adapter and then call notifyDataSetChanged() method :

```
listAdapter.clear();
listitems.add("item");
listAdapter.addAll(listitems);
listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: It still won't load the page. But I found out that if I take out the switch case and just leave what is in there, then the app crashes.

Comment: Try replacing getView() with rootView like  Button b = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);

Answer (score 0):

Remove. listview.setadapter() from onclick
And add it to createView

And add in onclick()-

listItems.add();
adapter notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

Two things I noticed:

1.Don't use `getView()` on your `onCreateView` method, use the view you just inflated:

```
Button b = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
b.setOnClickListener(this);
```

2.Your onClick method should look like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button:
            listItems.add("New Item");
            myListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I also tried this but the page loader is the only thing that appears.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by "page loader"?